# Access object data javascript in IE

Tags: javascript, object

I need to access to a Javascript Object data.
I has different layout in chrome and IE...

I have no problem to accesso to data in chrome, the problem is in IE(10).
In this browser the object layout is the following:

```
    [object Object]
    >[functions]
    >__proto__
    >accelerationPos
...
```

I can access to `.__proto_` and `.accelerationPos_` iin this way:

```
console.log( myObj.__proto__ );
```

How can i access to data inside `[functions]` ?

Comment: How do you want to use them later?

Comment: myObj.functions.your_data

Answer (score 0):

```
function myFunc(a, b){ /**/}
myFunc.length // arity
function.toString() // "data inside"
```

Answer (score 0):

The better way is to use iternal IE bebugger.